# Rate of change of a function defined on natural numbers

Tags: calculus, functions, integers

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ be some decreasing, differentiable function. Then, the function $g : \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ defined as, $$g(x) = \dfrac{1 + 2f(x)}{1 - f(x)}$$ is also decreasing, as can easily be checked by the quotient rule for derivatives.

But if $f : \mathbb{N} \mapsto \mathbb{Q}$ be a decreasing function, can we say that the function $g(n) = \dfrac{1 + 2f(n)}{1 - f(n)}$ is also decreasing? How can this be proven?

I am actually working with $f(n) = \displaystyle\prod_{r = 2}^{r = n} \dfrac{r^3 - 1}{r^3 + 1}$. I tried finding the first few values of $g(n)$ and they are indeed decreasing. But I don't know how to *prove* that $g(n)$ is decreasing.

Thanks for any hints or ideas about this.

Comment: In both cases, derivatives aren't necessary: if $n\ge m$, so that $f(n) \le f(m)$, you can check directly from the definition and simple reasoning that $g(n) \le g(m)$.

Comment: I don't think your first statement is true if there is a solution for $f(x)=1$. Say $f(x)=-x+5$, which is decreasing. Then $f(0)=5$, $g(0)=-\frac{11}{4}$, $f(10)=-5$, $g(10)=-\frac{9}{6}$ and therefore $g(10)>g(5)$. So the function is not decreasing

Comment: @GregMartin Thanks for the help, I've solved the problem I was doing. Sometimes one forgets to do the basics before trying the advanced.

Comment: @Andrei The function $g(x)$ in this case has a discontinuity at $x = 4$, but the two branches of the function separately satisfy the claim.